# Flutter Overflow Issue with Column

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a overflow Issue with a Column. I tried to use Extended but it don't helped me. I tried to to return a Column and inside that a Container but it also didn't fixed the Overflow Issue. I'd like that Size of the Box is variable so that when more text/Data is inside it is bigger and vise versa.

Can someone explain me what my Issue there is?

**Code**

```
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
import 'package:built_value/serializer.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_form_bloc/flutter_form_bloc.dart';
import 'package:mealapp/models/global.dart';
import 'package:mealapp/models/serializers.dart';
import 'package:mealapp/models/shopping_list/shopping_list.dart';
import 'package:mealapp/router/router.gr.dart';

class ShoppingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: darkGreyColor,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => ExtendedNavigator.rootNavigator
            .pushNamed(Routes.shoppingFormScreen),
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: redColor,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 30),
            height: 160,
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(50),
              ),
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            child: Text(
              "Shop Plan",
              style: mealPlanTitleStyle,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream:
                  Firestore.instance.collection('shopping_list').snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  final meals = <ShoppingList>[];
                  for (final doc in snapshot.data.documents) {
                    final meal = serializers.deserialize(
                      doc.data,
                      specifiedType: const FullType(ShoppingList),
                    ) as ShoppingList;
                    meals.add(meal);
                  }

                  if (meals.isEmpty) {
                    return Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'You have no Item inside the Meal list.',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: meals.length,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemExtent: 100,
                    primary: false,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ShoppingListCard(meals[index]);
                    },
                  );
                }
                return SizedBox.shrink();
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ShoppingListCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final ShoppingList shoppingList;

  const ShoppingListCard(this.shoppingList);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            '${shoppingList.items}',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(width: 8, height: 50),
              FlatButton(
                color: Colors.red,
                onPressed: () => (null), //Edit delete Data from Firestore
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadiusDirectional.circular(12)),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Delete',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white)),
                    Icon(Icons.delete_forever, color: Colors.white),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24)),
        color: lightBlueColor,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: App Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `Text` widget which is overflowing in `Container` and set the overflow property to `Text` widget.

Example:

```
....

child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
         Expanded(
            child: Container (
            child: Text(
            '${shoppingList.items}',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20, 
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, 
                color: Colors.white),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
           overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis
     ),),),

          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(width: 8, height: 50),
              FlatButton(

.....
```

Docs:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/TextOverflow-class.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html

Comment: Thanks for your help, now i have the Problem that not the hole Text is Shown. How do i fix this? It is just showing at the End three dots

Comment: Do one thing, give Container a color of red, run it and show me the snapshot.
Also give Container width of double.infinity

Comment: This is the Link where i Uploaded both Pictures.
https://imgur.com/a/rDk5GZu

Comment: Output is exactly what it supposed to be. Do you want to show entire text in there? Because of Overflow property the text which is going beyond our parent Container is being clipped and that's why three dots.

Comment: Yeah, i want to show the hole Text, even when the Box is taking up the hole Screen.

Comment: Here is the one thing you can do to shoe entire text in there, replace Expanded widget by SingleChildScrollView. You will have entire text and it will be scrollable. Also remove overflow property after that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215700/discussion-between-ketan-ramteke-and-tempelritter).